# how to execute mutliple queries and return the cumulative response using node/express/sqllite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, api, express

I am fairly new to node and its family, pardon me for any technical mistake that I make in explaining.

I am writing an API call using node that should connect to the sqllite DB and execute two queries an update and an insert.

I want to understand how to execute multiple queries within the same API and capture the output for both and return it in  the final response

```
app.get("/processing/updateandcreate/query/:ProcessID", (req, res, next) => {

var resultFinal;

db.run( `UPDATE PROCESS set CurrentStatus  = 'Query' where ProcessID=5`, {}, function (err,rows){
    if (err){
                res.status(400).json({"error": err.message})
                return;
            }
    resultFinal = resultFinal + rows;
});

db.run(`INSERT INTO QUERY RecordID values('1')`, {}, function (err, res2) {
            if (err){
                res.status(400).json({"error": err.message})
                return;
            }
            resultFinal = resultFinal + rows;
    });

        //I want to pass the result of both the queries here
res.json({
        message:"Okay"
    })   
 });
```

These commands did get executed while testing the API but it throws this error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

I think this probably happens when we are trying to send multiple responses.

Please help to sort this.

(I am writing a get Call, ideally which shouldn't be the case, but because of some config issue we are only able to run get calls to our app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a callback async library like `async` to orchestrate the multiple async actions or use native promises to the same effect. These days I prefer native promises. Node.js comes with a utility method `promisify` that converts callbacks into promises. With its help your code becomes:

```
const { promisify } = require('util')
const runAsync = promsifiy(db.run.bind(db))
app.get("/processing/updateandcreate/query/:ProcessID", async (req, res, next) => {

  // resultFinal is row[][]
  try {

    const [updateList, insertList] = await Promise.all([
      runAsync(`UPDATE PROCESS set CurrentStatus  = 'Query' where ProcessID=5`, {}),
      runAsync(`INSERT INTO QUERY RecordID values('1')`, {})
    ])

        //I want to pass the result of both the queries here
    res.json({
        updateList,
        insertList,
        message:"Okay"
    })   
   } catch(err) {
      res.status(400).send(err.message)
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks @CaptEmulation, However I made a mistake while. explanation, when I say cumulative, I mean I need to send result of both the queries in response however there should be some way to differentiate which part of response is from query1 and which part from query2. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Thanks, Can't we achieve this by using db.serialize(), after posting question I came across that method and tried using it but that also doesn't work, It probably should, Any idea why that wouldn't work

Comment: sorry... I'm actually not familiar with your db library (or even which db library it might be)... I just know promises